# Como abrir um website VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Olá, eu encontrei um código que entra em um site e faz autenticação. Após isso ele está na home page do site. Eu queria colocar para esse código entrar em um outro link, mas sem fechar o Internet Explorer que está aberto e autenticado. Primeira parte do código ele entra no site e autentica (essa eu já tenho), segunda parte ele escreve um outro link e é redirecionado, por exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/.

Segue o Código:

```
Sub Login()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim URL As String
Dim objElement As Object
Dim IE As Object
Dim IEapp As Object
Dim enderecoDaUrl As String



On Error GoTo Err_Clear
   sURL = "https://clientes.tray.com.br/?redirect=redirected"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
   oBrowser.Silent = True
   oBrowser.timeout = 60
   oBrowser.navigate sURL
   oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document
    HTMLDoc.all.loja.Value = Range("D4").Value
    HTMLDoc.all.usuario.Value = Range("D2").Value
    HTMLDoc.all.senha.Value = Range("D3").Value

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For

Next
Err_Clear:

Resume Next
Sleep (5000)

'AQUI IRIA A SEGUNDA PARTE'

End Sub
```

Após ir para essa segunda parte, ao entrar no link, é feito automaticamente o download de um arquivo .zip....Voces tem algum outro código pra abrir esse arquivo zip que foi baixado em uma outra sheet do excel que estou trabalhando?

Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,

Eu testei o código acima e o que ocorreu foi que, após a execução da primeira parte (que acessa e autentica no site da Tray), abriu uma nova aba no Internet Explorer sem fechar a página da Tray (que, no meu caso, obviamente não autenticou, dado que não tenho os valores de usuário e senha).

Ou seja, não ocorreu o problema mencionado e eu não fiz nenhuma alteração no código. Era isso mesmo o que precisava executar?

Já quanto a descompactar e copiar um arquivo Zip, creio que o código abaixo irá ajudar:

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim oApp As Object
Dim Fname As Variant
Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
Dim DefPath As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim WB  As Variant

'O código abaixo vai solicitar o caminho onde o arquivo zip se encontra.
    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", _
                                        MultiSelect:=False)
    If Fname = False Then
        'Do nothing
    Else

        'Este código vai pegar a pasta root principal, pode ser substituído por outro caminho se preferir
        DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
            DefPath = DefPath & "\"
        End If

        'Este código definirá o nome da pasta a ser criado
        strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss")
        FileNameFolder = DefPath & "MinhaPastaExtraida " & strDate & "\"
'O código abaixo irá criar o nome para a pasta onde irá colocar os arquivos extraídos
        MkDir FileNameFolder

        'Extrai o arquivo zip
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    'Cola os arquivos extraidos para pasta destino
        oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items

    'Procura o arquivo a ser aberto
    WB = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", MultiSelect:=False)
    'Abre a planilha
    Workbooks.Open WB
    'Copia a aba da planilha extraída para a planilha em que você está trabalhando (substitua o nome "Pasta4.xlsm" abaixo pelo nome da sua planilha)
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("Pasta4.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    'Volta para a primeira aba (substitua o nome "Planilha1" abaixo pelo nome da aba da planilha em que você está trabalhando)
    Set WB = Workbooks("Pasta4.xlsm")
    WB.Sheets("Planilha1").Select
    WB.Sheets("Planilha1").Range("A1").Select
    
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
    End If


End Sub
```

Espero que ajude. Qualquer problema, me avise!